# Do you get two handed weapon bonus damage with Mythic Power Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, mythic-adventures

Mythic Power Attack says...

> When you use Power Attack, you gain a +3 bonus on melee damage rolls instead of +2. When your base attack bonus reaches +4 and every 4 points thereafter, the amount of bonus damage increases by +3 instead of +2.
>
> In addition, the bonus damage from this feat is doubled on a critical hit, before it’s multiplied by the weapon’s critical multiplier.
>
> You can expend one use of mythic power when you activate Power Attack to ignore the penalties on melee attack rolls and combat maneuver checks for 1 minute.

It doesn't mention that two handed weapon (“THW”) damage is increased but the normal Power Attack rules should still apply (i.e. +50% for THW) since the feat doesn't say otherwise.

So wielding THW's should equal +4 damage per -1 to the attack, advancing as normal for each 4 levels gained.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, you gain +50% from using the weapon two-handed.

[Mythic Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-feats/power-attack-mythic/) is not an independant ability from [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat-final/). Rather, it improves your Power Attack, meaning that everything not explicitly mentioned and replaced by the Mythic version of the feat still applies.

> **This bonus to damage** is increased by half (+50%) if you are making an attack with a two-handed weapon, a one handed weapon using two hands, or a primary natural weapon that adds 1-1/2 times your Strength modifier on damage rolls. This bonus to damage is halved (–50%) if you are making an attack with an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon.

So if you bonus is normally +2, it is increased to +3 with *Mythic Power Attack*. Then increased again by +50% if wielding the weapon two-handed, and reduced by 50% if using an off-hand weapon or secondary natural weapon.

Comment: Thank you for the added clarity for the off-hand damage as well...!
:D

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, it equals to +4.5 damages per -1 to the attack, rounded down: when you reach +4 BAB it becomes +9 damages for -2 to the attack, and so on.

Comment: Yup...I do believe you are correct. At -4 to the attack you get +18 instead of just +16...! Thank you pointing that out!